# Decode/Encode multi-line string fields from YAML using golang

Tags: go, yaml

YAML files can contain fields with "multi-line string" data. Example below:

```
Data:
  Foo: |
    enemies=aliens
    lives=3
    enemies.cheat=true
    enemies.cheat.level=noGoodRotten
```

How can I properly encode and decode these in Golang and what should be the type of the `Data` field, `map[string][]byte`?

I tried:

```
import (
    yamlv2 "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type data struct {
  Data map[string][]byte
}

func decode(bytes []byte) (*data, error) {
  d := &data{}

  err := yamlv2.Unmarshal(bytes, d)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  return d, nil
}
```

Also see in [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/F2AQkwBpQKv).

Comment: What about that example is "binary"? It looks like completely normal ASCII text.

Comment: My bad, not sure what is the term to refer to this kind of field type. It is a multiline string?

Comment: Yes, I would call it a multi-line string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would parse a multi-line string the same way as a normal string:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
    "log"
)

var yamlString = `
Data:
  Foo: |
    enemies=aliens
    lives=3
    enemies.cheat=true
    enemies.cheat.level=noGoodRotten`

type data struct {
    Data map[string]string `yaml:"Data"`
}

func main() {
    t := data{}

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(yamlString), &t)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }

    if foo, ok := t.Data["Foo"]; ok {
        fmt.Printf("--- t:\n%v\n\n", foo)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I have updated my question. I need to decode/encode the "multi-line string" fields.